# HTTP reponse should have image but instead result with `loaded: 43094 total: 43094 type: 3` in Angular client

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpclient

I have a form in angular, one of the form inputs is an image.
The form is sent to the server, if the reponse is sucess, the response should have the image as its body, so that it is available in the browser's devtools `network > preview` section.

On success, the client should render the image got back from the server.

This is the expected response preview:

[image]

And this is the actual response:

[image]

This is the code of the request to server and the handling of the response:

```js
this.certificateService.AddCertificate(this.info).subscribe(
    (upload: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (upload.type) {
            case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                this.isNewPic = false;
                this.certificateService.SetImage(upload);
                break;
        }
    },
    error => { }
);
```

The issue is that as a response I get the following instead of an image:

`loaded: 43094 total: 43094 type: 3`

**What causes this issue? and how can that be fixed?**

**Edit : **

```
AddCertificate(item: AddCertificateModel): Observable<any> {
    const Url = `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/Certificate/Template/Preview`;
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for (const key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            if (item[key] instanceof File) {
                formData.append(key, item[key], item[key].name);
            }
            else if (key == 'KeywordSampleData') {
                formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(item.KeywordSampleData));
            }
            else {
                formData.append(key, item[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.httpClient
        .post(Url, formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
        })
        .pipe(map(response => response || {} as HttpEvent<any>));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [`reportProgress`](https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress) option on your request, that means that as long as the request is still in process (the response hasn't done yet), you'll get events that report the request status.

What happened in your code is that in the `switch` statement you handle only the `HttpEventType.DownloadProgress`, but this status does not represent the final response from the server. The `upload.type` that you need is `HttpEventType.Response`.
To get the image, add the relevant case to your code

```
this.certificateService.AddCertificate(this.info).subscribe(
    (upload: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (upload.type) {
            case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                console.log('the process is done');
                break;
            case HttpEventType.Response:
                console.log('I got the image!');
                this.isNewPic = false;
                this.certificateService.SetImage(upload);
                break;
        }
    },
    error => { }
);
```

Comment: when i use this type `HttpEventType.Response` it not come into that case .

Comment: I actually against using `switch` statements. Try to `console.log(upload)` before the switch, and see what you get in the subscription stream.

Comment: when i log the upload it show me this data `loaded: 43094 total: 43094 type: 3

`

Comment: Can you share the code of `this.certificateService.AddCertificate` method?

Comment: If possible add a screenshot of the request. And I see you have some errors in the console, please attach them too if relevant.